# How to flush a directory as a way to fix FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, .net, windows, filesystemwatcher

As shown in [this post, **`FileSystemWatcher`** is unreliable](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/4465cafb-f4ed-434f-89d8-c85ced6ffaa8/) because of Windows disk caching. The poster showed that the class misses roughly 0.15% - 0.35% of all events regardless of optimizations and [InternalBufferSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.internalbuffersize.aspx). Even drivers suffer from this, so it's not inherently a fault of FileSystemWatcher.

The poster suggests a way to deal with this problem - flushing entire volume. However I don't want to do that - the cache is there for a reason and it requires admin privileges. Is it possible to flush just the watched directory and achieve the same results of making FileSystemWatcher 100 % accurate? I don't know much about [**FlushFileBuffers**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but the poster's solution specifically flushes entire volume, even though flushing just the directory would be obviously a better solution.

Is there any .NET way to flush a directory or a specified file (non-opened)? I mean the **real flush**, which waits for confirmation from the disk itself. For example, [FileStream.Flush(void)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bw4h516.aspx) flushes just the .NET buffers, but not the OS buffer (unlike [FileStream.Flush(bool)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee474552.aspx) with *true* argument in .NET 4 and better). I want to flush files opened by other apps.

If not, is it even possible to use FlushFileBuffers to flush a directory (maybe it supports just files and volumes, which would be weird though)? Also a non-admin solution would be more than ideal, because in admin mode I could just use Change Journal.

Comment: You can't force other applications to flush their internal buffers.  The only *flushing* option is to flush the whole volume.  You could keep track of files in an individual directory and periodically compare the collection to what's actually on disk.  e.g. use `System.Threading.Timers.Timer` to periodically call `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` to compare new/different/deleted files...

Comment: Is `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` going to flush the file system cache? As far as I know, `FileSystemWatcher` is not picking the changes because they are not yet physically on disk. And if `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` will flush the cache, then maybe just periodically calling that method should be enough, as the *flushed events* should automatically pop in FSW. By the way it's not about flushing other app's internal buffers. It's about flushing OS/FS buffers.